# Python convert string to null terminated byte string

Tags: python, string, hex, byte

I'm trying to convert a python string to a null terminated byte string. I don't need this string for use in my python program, but I need to have the string in this format and use this output somewhere else.

But basically, for example, I would like to convert the string `"cat"` to `"\x63\x61\x74"` if possible, in some way or another.

I wasn't able to find a suitable solution for this problem so far.

---

I have one possible solution, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. This just places the hex values in a list. Not in the exact format above, but similar outcome.

```py
text = "asjknlkjsndfskjn"
hexlist = []

for i in range(0, len(str)):
    hexlist.append(hex(ord(str[i:i+1])))

print(hexlist)
```

Comment: So, just to get it right: for instance the second element of your new string would be `x`, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
>>> bytes('cat', 'ascii')
b'cat'
```

For null termination simply add NUL:

```
>>> bytes('cat', 'ascii') + b'\x00'
b'cat\x00'
```

**Edit:** To store the hex representation in a string you could do something like this:

```
>>> ''.join(['\\'+hex(b)[1:] for b in bytes('cat', 'ascii')])
'\\x63\\x61\\x74'
>>> print(_)
\x63\x61\x74
```

Comment: I need the format of the result string to be in hex, as in `"\x63\x61\x74"`

Comment: It is already. `b'cat'` indicates a [bytes object or bytestring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) and is identical to `b'\x63\x61\x74'`. If it's formatting you're after, you can get the hex representation like this: `bytes('cat', 'ascii').hex()`.

Comment: @Flengo what, **exactly** do you want? Do you want a byte string that has the bytes you are representing in hex, or do you want that actual hex representation as a byte string?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with my question. I need the hex representation as a string. So ultimately, I don't need `b'cat'` but I need `'\x63\x61\x74'` as a string instead, based on `'cat'` or whatever else it might be.